# How to change material theme text color

Tags: material-design, visual-studio-code

I'm a big fan of material theme on vscode, however on the lighter themes the non-keyword (the grey parts) text is very hard to read on a completely white background:

[image]

Can someone point me in the right direction to change the text color?

Answer (score 0):

I have not managed to find a complete way to change all the non-highlighted text, I did received some help form the maintainer that gets me kinda where I want.

On your vscode settings:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Material Theme Lighter High Contrast]": {
      "textMateRules": [
        {
          "scope": [
            "variable",
            "foreground",
          ],
          "settings": {
            "foreground": "#2C2C2C",
          }
        },
        {
          "scope": "string",
          "settings": {
            "foreground": "#00416A",
          }
        },
        {
          "scope": "comment",
          "settings": {
            "foreground": "#FF9900",
          }
        }
      ]
    },
```